Does $f'(x) = 0$ necessarily mean that there must be either one of a Local Maxima, Minima, or Point of Inflection?
I am studying calculus and am trying to understand the behavior of functions at points where their derivative equals zero.
I want to know if having $f'(x) = 0$ at a point $x$ always means there is either a local maximum, a local minimum, or a point of inflection at that point.
The definition in my course slides for inflection points: Suppose $f'(c) = 0$. If $c$ does not give a local maximum or minimum, then
$c$ is called a point of (horizontal) inflection.

By definition, yes. We define a horizontal inflection to be a point $x$ where $f'(x)=0$ but it isn't a local minima or a local maxima.

Are there any conditions on $f$? For example, do you want to assume $f$ is continuous/differentiable everywhere?

@DanieĺP no it is not true. I also don't believe it would be true even if $f$ were restricted to being continuous and differentiable everywhere - consider $x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$

@NinadMunshi The above function obviously requires to be defined at $x = 0$ to be differentiable at  $x = 0$. Could we find a more straightforward, non-piecewise function, which is both continuous and differentiable everywhere (like a smooth function something like a polynomial with trigonometric functions) which can still demonstrate that the above property does not necessarily apply. I'm interested in traditional function forms without resorting to discontinuities or piecewise definitions.

"straightforward", "traditional function forms" are nonsense terms. Just because a function comes up early in a curriculum, that does not give it any inherent magic proeprties. In mathematics you must be precise. Differentiability, some kind of regularity, etc is how you should specify a restriction. Otherwise your idea of what a function can or can't be is narrow minded and objectively incorrect.

@NinadMunshi Functions like combinations of Polynomials, trigonometric, hyperbolic, exponential, rational, logarithmic etc. I want non piecewise functions which do not have discontinuities and are smooth.

I am not really defining or coming up with a definition of a function here, I agree with the fact that the answer to my above question is no. I am just looking for some "elementary" or some "simple" case which is non piecewise. For example if you were to explain the fact that their exists a case where $f^{'}(x)$ is $0$ but it is not an extrema you would go for $f(x) = x^3$.

No. Consider
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}x^2 & x\in\Bbb{Q} \\ -x^2 & x\notin \Bbb{Q}\end{cases}$$
The derivative equals zero at $x=0$ and only exists at that point. But it would not classify as any of those three types of points.

What if we don't use piecewise functions...does the statement holds good in that case $?$

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad piecewise functions aren't a meaningful distinction as it is a reflection of our notation rather than any intrinsic property of the function - every function is piecewise. Consider $$\sin x = \begin{cases}0 & x=0,\pi,\cdots \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & x = \frac{\pi}{4},\cdots \ \vdots & \vdots\end{cases}$$ as a description of the sine function. While a little silly, the cases need not be countable.

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad every function can be written as "piecewise". What exactly do you mean?

Hmm you all are right....i actually meant those traditional functions like algebraic, trigonometric, hyperbolic, exponential etc @freakish

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad I don't think a differentiable everywhere function counter example exists so most traditional functions will satisfy it

@RandomGuy this is not true - see my comment in the OP or the other answer

Ah ye that works mb

The classification of critical points as maxima, minima or POI falls-on and holds for continuous functions on an open or closed interval + adequate smoothness. The meaning behind these classifications loses value amongst discontinuity, as they are not only a descriptor for the instaneous rate of change, but more the behaviour of change relative to local points of an interval - hence the 2nd derivative test. Discontinuity can remove the reliability of the tests by misleading the nature of critical point.
Take this function as an example:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 
x^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & \text{if } x \neq 0 \\ 
0 & \text{if } x = 0 
\end{cases}
$$
Which oscillates rapidly as $ x \rightarrow 0$. The nature of the critical point is not simply maxima, minima or a POI due to the oscillatory nature near the removable discontinuity at $x=0$.
